# Why is the output of this query being returned like this?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a T-SQL query :

```
select 
    CAST(0 as float(53)),
    CONVERT(nvarchar(max),CAST(0 as float(53)),128)
```

the output of which is

```
0  ,  0.0E0
```

Can some one explain why it is not `0 , 0`?  The database is SQL Server 2008.

Comment: According to msdn, format 128 is deprecated and might not be supported in future releases.

Comment: @Andomar:  I think you need to move your comment as an answer.

Comment: Why not to use 0:
select CAST(0 as float(53)),CONVERT(nvarchar(max),CAST(0 as float(53)),0)

Comment: @Andomar : I know format 128 is deprecated but this is the best we could have done to remove trailing 0's when the data is numeric. We plan to stick to SQL Server 2008 for some time before we move to other version. Thanks

Comment: @msi77 : I want to know why in this case ?

Comment: @Egalitarian - Why shouldn't it be? Have you any documentation that indicates it should behave differently?

Comment: @MartinSmith :What 128 does in this case is that it removes the trailing 0's . Now, in same case if you give input like select CAST(1 as float(53)),CONVERT(nvarchar(max),CAST(1 as float(53)),128) then the output will be 1,1 not 1,1.0e1.

Comment: @Egalitarian - `SELECT CAST(CAST(1 AS FLOAT) AS nvarchar(max)), CONVERT(nvarchar(max),CAST(1 as float(53)))` both do that too.

Comment: @MartinSmith : My question in this case is why the output is in scientific notation in case of 0, but not in case of others.

Comment: Isn't the question moot if it's being depreciated?  Shouldn't you use 1 or 2 instead of 128?

Comment: Being deprecated doesn't mean that its not currently supported. 128 is pretty generic to remove trailing 0's that is why I am using it over here. It works for float and numeric data types both.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax for CONVERT:

```
 CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )
```

[style] for float data type :

```
0 (default)   A maximum of 6 digits. Use in scientific notation, when appropriate.
1 Always 8 digits. Always use in scientific notation.
2 Always 16 digits. Always use in scientific notation.
126, 128, 129 Included for legacy reasons and might be deprecated in a future release.
```

You can use below command to get expected result :

```
CONVERT(nvarchar(max),CAST(0 as float(53)),0)
```